# Example for polymer 1.0 list-view element?

Tags: javascript, html, listview, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there an example or documents on creating list-views with item click(row-item) listeners? If yes, is it possible to have single selection and multi selection behaviors on the list-view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Iron-list](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-elements) should come out in couple weeks. Meantime you can use [core-list](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-list.html) from polymer 0.5.

Comment: Fwiw, `iron-list` is only necessary when you have a very large list and need virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

I use iron-selector to handle lists in Polymer 1.0.
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-selector

Comment: `iron-selector` is an excellent choice if your list can be rendered all at once (doesn't require virtualization).